# Extract Xml Element from a larger string

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a string that starts with an xml element then proceeds with regular text after the Element has ended.

Like so:

```
<SomeElement SomeAtt="SomeValue"><SomeChild/></SomeElement> More random text.
```

I want to parse the first part into an XElement and then separate out the following text into a string variable.
I have considered just counting anglebrackets, but there is legal XML that would throw me off.
I would prefer to use the out-of-the-box parsers.
I have tried using XmlReader and XElement.Parse method. I would like them to stop after the element is read instead of throwing exceptions because of the unexpected text after the Xml element. I haven't been able to thus far. XmlReader has a ReadSubtree method, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Edit

- Additional Info: The random text may contain angle brackets.
- Additional Info: Conceptually, XML may contain xml comments, which may contain non matching brackets. So, it is desirable that the solution account for this in order to be generally applicable, but not necessary in my specific case.

Comment: You have errors in your XML and the is why the XMLreader is giving exceptions..  You should fix the errors instead of looking for a kludge to work around these errors.

Comment: Can you now read the file with XElement.Parse.  Do you need additional help?

Comment: No, XElement.Parse will complain about the "More random text." part. Specifically, it will throw exception "Data at the root level is invalid". If you see the comment section of the answer from har07, it may be clearer what the problem is.

Comment: I meant "no" as in "I cannot read the text with XElement.Parse". And "Yes, if you have a good solution I would like to hear it".

Answer (score 5):

One possible simple approach maybe to wrap the entire string within a root node to make it valid XML and parseable by `XElement` or `XDocument` :

```
var xml = @"<SomeElement SomeAtt=""SomeValue""><SomeChild/></SomeElement> More random text.";
xml = string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", xml);
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var element = doc.Root.Elements().First();
var trailingString = doc.Root.LastNode;

Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(trailingString.ToString());
```

Console Output:

```
<SomeElement SomeAtt="SomeValue">
  <SomeChild />
</SomeElement>

 More random text.
```

Comment: That's a smart solution. But would it not require me to somehow escape the random text in order to make it valid XText?

Comment: Exactly, if you really hit that situation, then I'm afraid you'll have to find another way around. The problem in that case I think is, you don't want to escape but the random text (otherwise, f.e, `>` in the XML part will be escaped to `&gt;`), so you'll need to separate the random text from the XML part. And that's the original problem :(

Comment: No XML parsing library as far as I know, can deal with invalid XML, or stop parsing at the end of valid portion. Not even `XmlReader`'s `ReadSubtree()`, from what I read, it is supposed to read sub-tree of a larger *valid* XML tree

Comment: Yes, that is my current status. It appears that I have to resort to angle bracket counting and have special handling for XML comments so they don't throw off my counting. It is regrettable, though, since the standard library parsers already do this.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you don't need to go that far to parsing the XML manually. Does the random text always come after the XML? If it does, why not just try to find the last closing bracket? then you can do substring from start to the last closing bracket to get your valid XML..

Comment: Yes, it does. So I have the starting bracket. But how do you propose I identify the closing bracket of the XElement without doing bracket counting? The random text can also contain brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML requires an identification line (normal first line) and only one root node to be valid for the XMLReader to read without errors.

Comment: The input data is not xml. The input data is a string where the string starts with an Xml element serving as a header with metadata. My question is how to extract the Xml element from the rest of the input data, preferably using the existing XML aware parsers in .NET BCL. The problem is to get them to "stop" after reading the Xml element.